# User Management in AWS EMR and Hive

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

Our company has an EMR running which executes spark jobs and usually never terminated. By default, the hive database is setup with only one user "hadoop" and password is empty. Our clients wants us to not share this credentials with everyone, instead onboard users with their own user names to access hive. Also, if the EMR is recreated, we should not be wanting to recreate the users as well.

One solution that I thought is to store all user information (username, password) in a database like mongo DB and create the users using a script during EMR bootstrap. Although, need to tackle how to add the users after the EMR is created.

Is there any better approach for achieving this?

Comment: LDAP: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implementing-ldap-authentication-for-hive-on-a-multi-tenant-amazon-emr-cluster/

Comment: Unfortunately, its difficult to get access to organization LDAP. I need to look for other options